# Convert Object array to String Array

Tags: javascript

I have an Object array that looks like the following:

```
var array = [
  {'id':1,'description':test},
  {'id':2,'description':test},
  {'id':3,'description':test}
]
```

And I want to convert it to look like this:

```
var newArray = [
  1, 2, 3
]
```

So it's basically taking the object array, extracting the `id`'s out of the objects, and creating a new array that contains the `id`'s that were extracted. Is there a way to do this in one line? Even better if a new array doesn't have to get created and `array` is just updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var test ="sai";
var array = [
  {'id':1,'description':test},
  {'id':2,'description':test},
  {'id':3,'description':test}
]

console.log(array.map(function(obj){return obj.id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate the `array` using [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and populate `newArray`

```
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(funtion(element){
   newArray.push(element.id);
});
console.log( newArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map(function(element) {return element.id})
```

OP Requirement: better if array is just updated

```
array = array.map(function(element) {return element.id})
```

Comment: @TaoP.R.O.P asked for it

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map(function (item) { 
    return item["id"];
}
```

If you'd like to have anew instance of the mapped array:

```
var newarray = [];
array.forEach(function (item) {
    newarray.push(item["id"]);
}
```